# Is it possible to turn vertices and move them only in one direction?

Tags: modeling

I want to turn some verts, but I wan't them to be still in the original x and y cooridanetes. Is there a way which doesn't need the boolean cut?

So I wan't the result from B with, and not from A.

[image: Cylinder with extrusion and rotaion; Cylinder with extrusion and cut]

Comment: maybe what you're looking for is the Shear tool?

Comment: you can knife project a plane rotated at the wanted angle.

Comment: Here is what I consider is the best way to produce that effect.  I use the knife tool.  When you press "k" to activate the tool, you then hit "z", which allows you to cut all the way through the object, instead of going all around.  You then go to side view and cut a straight line through.